# How to call Ajax request continuously in jquery until we receive the response

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, settimeout

There is one ajax call happening in my service which is taking more time to fulfill the request. But in the end, if I check the logs this request is getting successful in 2 mins.

Now the problem is modern browsers don't wait for this request for more than 1 min. If the request is not completed within one min it fails with HTTP error 504.

With the below code, I am trying to call the ajax call continuously. But this creates a new request every time. My requirement is I should call this ajax request continuously until I get a response for it. Also with the below code, it's always calling the ajax request. Not sure how to stop that.

```
function fetchdata(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'fetch_details.php',
  type: 'post',
  success: function(data){
   // Perform operation on return value
   alert(data);
  },
  complete:function(data){
   setTimeout(fetchdata,5000);
  }
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 setTimeout(fetchdata,5000);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect that you will want to investigate why your server is taking 2 minutes to respond to a request. If the request is for data, and the server is taking 2 minutes to generate the record set, you might be asking for too much data all at once.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, **you cant control** when **client** will drop the request if it takes above the average time, since you dont know what's in between (firewalls also cut such requests).

Still, if your server-side scrips are handling complex data and you need many minutes, a smart aproach would be to **adapt in new standards** and make 3 type of requests :

1. one for calling the script that **proccess the data**,
2. one that **asks every X seconds if the data are processed** and
3. one that, *once the data are processed*, **stops the check loop and grabs the results**.